# Using #states to disable a field collection field

Tags: javascript

I am trying to disable a date field's second value, inside a field collection, but it isn't working.

My hook_form_alter has this:

```
  $form['field_certification']['und'][0]['field_validity']['und'][0]['#states'] = array(
        'disabled' => array(
          'input[name="field_certification[und][0][field_auto_calculate_validity][und]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
        ),
      );
```

The HTML for the date field is here:

```
<input class="date-clear form-text hasDatepicker date-popup-init" type="text" id="edit-field-certification-und-0-field-validity-und-0-value2-datepicker-popup-0" name="field_certification[und][0][field_validity][und][0][value2][date]" value="07/23/2014" size="20" maxlength="30">
```

The checkbox is here:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="edit-field-certification-und-0-field-auto-calculate-validity-und" name="field_certification[und][0][field_auto_calculate_validity][und]" value="1" class="form-checkbox">
```

Could it be because I'm not specifically selecting the (second) value of the date field?

Comment: By 'disable a date field collection field's second value', do you mean to prevent the display of the second form element within that collection?

Comment: I have a field collection, and I have a date field inside of that field collection. That date field has both start and end dates (or to and from dates, whatever you want to call them). I want to disable the second one when a given checkbox is checked.

Comment: I missed the relevance of the checkbox. I guess you would need to do this with javascript/jquery (adding a click event to the checkbox to disable the field), though maybe Drupal's AHAH functionality could be of use: https://www.drupal.org/node/331941

Comment: updated solution, hope helps

Answer (score 0):

My original answer totally missed the point (apologies), this is updated version:

I do not think you can use Drupal's form api #state property to accomplish what you would like. States can be used to hide, reveal and disable whole form elements, such as a fieldset, text input or date field, but you aim to disable one part of a single (contrib) element (ie the second value of a date_combo field provided by the date module).

There are two possible solutions:

- load your own jquery when the form is loaded, and [add a change()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252136/jquery-show-extra-field-conditional-on-current-inputs-value) function to disable the relevant date field component
- separate the start/end dates into separate date fields and use the drupal #states functionality (as above) to disable the (whole) second date field:

  ```
  $form['field_certification']['und'][0]['field_validity']['#states'] = array(
  'disabled' => array(
      ':input[name="field_certification[und][0][field_auto_calculate_validity][und]"]' => array(
          'checked' => true
      ),
  )
  ```

  );

I hope this helps, I played around with it on a blank d7 install, and this was the only way I could get your intended functionality to work.

Comment: apologies for repeated updates

Comment: No, I can get it to disable the date field generally, but I want only the second date value to be grayed out. And yes, I corrected the lack of : in my code.

Comment: I will try to replicate your issue.